# WatchKit Number Input Controls?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch

Is there any control (including third party libraries) to allow the user to enter/type in numbers on the AppleWatch? I know dictation is the standard interface for text input on the watch, but I am unsure about how that will be processed by the WatchKit dictation system. (`One-Hundred Forty Three` vs `143`.)

Comment: In all Apple's videos, user can input numbers by spinning digital crown (on the right side of watch).
But I can't find any solutions to work with crown in AppleWatch Simulator.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to enter a passcode or something simple like that, there is no built-in API to achieve that (apart the dictation system but I don't think it is built specifically for numbers). It's very simple to build your own.

I built a calculator with a sort of numbers keyboard. Check it out here. It could be useful for your usage: https://github.com/BalestraPatrick/AppleWatchCalculator